# How to center text in Emacs?

Tags: text, emacs, centering

Is it possible in Emacs to transform this:

```
<!-- inclusion du code JavaScript    -->
<!-- inclusion des feuilles de style -->
<!-- definition du ZHO               -->
```

into this (approximate):

```
<!--   inclusion du code JavaScript  -->
<!-- inclusion des feuilles de style -->
<!--        definition du ZHO        -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've connected the dots below as an interactive command.  @nicolasdudebout's algorithm is more or less sound with the addition that a "hard" `move-to-column` is needed to select the rectangle.

select your interesting (without arrows) rectangle and run:

```
(defun center-rectangle (beg end)
  (interactive "*r")
  (kill-rectangle beg end)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (yank-rectangle)
    (setq fill-column (current-column))
    (center-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (move-to-column fill-column t)
    (kill-rectangle (point-min) (point)))
  (goto-char beg)
  (yank-rectangle))
```

Comment: This does work. Select the rectangle being ***not including*** the `<!--`s or `-->`.

Answer (score 3):

You set the variable `fill-column` to the nr. of columns.

Then you call `(center-line)`

Here is how you can do:

1. (setq fill-column 100)
2. Cut '<---' and '--->' on each line
3. You call (center-line)
4. call string-rectangle on the column 1 , and insert '<---'
5. call string-rectangle on last column , and insert '--->'

To arrive on the last column at the last step [3], you can do `(goto-char (point-min))`, then (end-of-line), and then call `(indent-line-to COL)`

Comment: Not quite what OP is asking for, since this won't adjust the spacing inside the comment delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a function or macro doing that using rectangles.
This would do the following:

- cut the rectangle containing the text only
- paste it in a temporary buffer
- set `fill-column` to the number of columns and use `center-line` (see alinsoar's answer)
- cut the result as a rectangle
- yank it back as a rectangle in the original buffer

Comment: How do I set fill-column to the number of columns ?

Comment: As event_jr is doing you can use `(setq fill-column (current-column))` since the current column is at the end of the rectangle when yanking.

Answer (score 1):

`set-justification-center`. There's also `set-justification-right` as you might expect. These functions include newlines in inappropriate locations thought, so it may break the paragraph lines.